# ODBC SQL Server how to fix How do I fix 'Invalid character value for cast specification'?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, odbc

I'm newby that about ODBC in C++, but probably somebody can help.
I try to insert datetime by using ODBC prepared statement

here is bind:

```
SQLRETURN rc = SQLBindParameter(hdc, i, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR,
SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 19, 0, (SQLPOINTER)value, 0, &len);
```

the value if const char* value="2017-10-17 00:08:22"
but error of execute is

> Invalid character value for cast specification

Any ideas?

Comment: always use a datetime format that is language neutral, like yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss for example. See http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Comment: I use in most of cases ISO 8601 format '2017-10-17T00:08:22' what is language neutral either, but I got the same error

Comment: but the value in your question is not in ISO 8601 format

Comment: I've tried already all formats, the issue is the same. Is it critical what I call as first prepare and then bind?